# ncurses terminal size

Tags: c, ncurses

How do I find the terminal width & height of an ncurses application?

Comment: @DylanJ, no need to put the answer in the question, especially once you've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`void getmaxyx(WINDOW *win, int y, int x);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxyx) i believe...

also, this may help...

[Getting terminal width in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)

Comment: Also: Don't forget that some operating systems have SIGWINCH which your process receives when the terminal is resized...

Comment: `initscr()` will clear screen. Is there any way which can get terminal size and don't clear screen?

Comment: Not sure this is true because `y` & `x` are not pointers and therefore the function will not copy anything to them.
And from `mkssoftware.com` : "`getbegyx() and getmaxyx() macros store the current beginning coordinates and size of the specified window.`"

Comment: @afr0ck As your quote states, those are all macros, so `y` and `x` do not need to be pointers. The macro works directly on the given variables, with no copy-assignment or pointers needed.

Answer (score 17):

ncurses applications normally handle `SIGWINCH` and use the `ioctl` with `TIOCGWINSZ` to obtain the system's notion of the screensize.  That may be overridden by the environment variables [`LINES`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-LINES) and [`COLUMNS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-COLUMNS) (see [`use_env`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env)).

Given that, the ncurses global variables [`LINES`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_variables.3x.html#h3-LINES) and [`COLS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_variables.3x.html#h3-COLS) are updated as a side-effect when `wgetch` returns `KEY_RESIZE` (in response to a `SIGWINCH`) to give the size of `stdscr` (the standard screen representing the whole terminal).

You can of course use [`getmaxx`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_legacy.3x.html), [`getmaxy`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_legacy.3x.html) and [`getmaxyx`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getyx.3x.html) to get one or both of the limits for the x- and y-ordinates of a window.  Only the last is standard (and portable).

Further reading:

- [Handling SIGWINCH (resize events)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#handle_resize) (ncurses FAQ)
- [**`is_term_resized`**,  **`resize_term`**,  **`resizeterm`**  —  change  the
     curses terminal size](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html)

Answer (score 3):

i'm using this code:

```
struct winsize size;
if (ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, (char *) &size) < 0)
    printf("TIOCGWINSZ error");
printf("%d rows, %d columns\n", size.ws_row, size.ws_col);
```

Comment: That's not very ncurses'ish.

Comment: Yes I used to... until I try to redirect or use a IDE like Netbeans... in those cases, the file descriptor must be changed (in case of redirecting from stdin, use STDOUT_FILENO; and using a IDE it's tricky when debugging/stepping you MUST have the "output" window opened).

Answer (score 1):

What about using `SCR_H` and `SCR_W`?

Answer (score 1):

> the variables COLS, LINES are initialized to the screen sizes after initscr().

Source: [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/windows.html)

I'm not sure if they get updated on resize though.