# Request terminal size [C - Linux]

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I'm trying to make a nice looking terminal game, but a lot of the things i'd like to do need a constant screen size. So i need the program to request a certain size every time it is ran. Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ncurses terminal size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811955/ncurses-terminal-size)

Comment: is it a really good idea to change the size of the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ncurses library has functionality for handling terminal sizes.  This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811955/ncurses-terminal-size) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c) regarding terminal dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the existing size, but you can't ask for a specific size. This terminal stuff was invented in a time where these sizes where hardcoded to be the physical size of the screen.