# printf() \t option

Tags: c, printf

When you are printing a tab character to the standard output using `printf` in C, it outputs some space which is apparently 4 characters in length.

```
printf("\t");
```

Is there a way by which I can control the tab width in the above case?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A tab is a tab. How many spaces it consumes is a display issue, and depends on the settings of your shell.

If you want to control the width of your data, then you could use the *width* sub-specifiers in the `printf` format string. For example,

```
printf("%5d", 2);
```

It's not a complete solution (if the value is longer than five characters, it will not be truncated), but it might be OK for your needs.

If you want complete control, you'll probably have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Actually for strings you can get truncation:  `printf("%5.5s","abcdefg");` will output "abcde". And if you always want the output left-aligned for cases where the string is less than 5 characters, use `"%-5.5s"`

Comment: @proFromDover : if you can limit yourself to strings, that's ok, yes.

Comment: I think it's the settings of the terminal, not the shell, what if the shell itself prints a tab character?

Answer (score 60):

That's something controlled by your terminal, not by `printf`.

`printf` simply sends a `\t` to the output stream (which can be a tty, a file, etc.). It doesn't send a number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If your [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) supports proper [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), there are escape sequences to set [tab stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop) to any location on the screen. The escape sequence `ESC [ 3 g` clears all tab stops, the escape sequence `ESC H` sets the tab stop at a specific location.

Below is an [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) example C program that provides a function that set's tab stops to the specified count of spaces. First all existing tabs are removed, then spaces are printed and in proper locations the tab stop is set. Then the cursor is rewind back to the start of the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>

int writestr(int fd, const char *s) {
    return write(fd, s, strlen(s)) == (ssize_t)strlen(s) ? 0 : -1;
}

int set_tab_stops(unsigned distance) {
    assert(distance > 0);
    // Using stdout here, stderr would be more reliable. 
    FILE *file = stdout;
    const int fd = fileno(file);
    // We have to flush stdout in order to use fileno.
    fflush(file);
    // Get terminal width.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c
    struct winsize w = {0};
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGWINSZ, &w) < 0) return -__LINE__;
    const unsigned cols = w.ws_col;
    // Remove all current tab stops.
    if (writestr(fd, "\033[3g") < 0) return -__LINE__;
    // Do horicontal tabs each distance spaces.
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
        if (i % distance == distance - 1) {
            if (writestr(fd, "\033H") < 0) return -__LINE__;
        }
        if (writestr(fd, " ") < 0) return -__LINE__;
    }
    // Clear the line and return to beginning of the line.
    if (writestr(fd, "\033[1K\033[G") < 0) return -__LINE__;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    set_tab_stops(10);
    printf("1\t2\t3\t4\n");
    set_tab_stops(5);
    printf("1\t2\t3\t4\n");
}
```

With [`xfce4-terminal`](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/start) the program outputs:

```
1        2         3         4
1   2    3    4
```