# How can I find the number of terminal columns from a C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, formatting, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting terminal width in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)

On Linux and OS X, my shell reports $COLUMNS has the width of the terminal window -- and resizing the window will adjust this shell variable.

But in my C/C++ program, getenv("COLUMNS") doesn't seem to find the variable.

Anybody have an explanation?  Or an alternate suggestion for letting my C++ program figure out the width of the terminal it's running in (for some help message word wrapping)?

Comment: `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` are *shell* variables, not *environment* variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);

    printf("lines %d\n", w.ws_row);
    printf("columns %d\n", w.ws_col);
    return 0;
}
```

Taken straight from: [Getting terminal width in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)

Comment: BTW this is not "portable" (not specified by POSIX) but works almost everywhere in practice.

Comment: Works great in my case, thanks!

Comment: You'll have to handle the `SIGWINCH` signal as well if you want to deal with resizing of the window.