# C++ How to get the window size (width and height)?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a graph and I need to know the size of the window the user is running the code in. I'm trying to scale the data so the data shows only on the size of the window, without wrapping or scrolling. I'm on windows but I want to use something similar to Linux equivalent

```
int lines = atoi(getenv("LINES") ;
int cols  = atoi(getenv("COLUMNS") ;
```

So I can scale numbers and show a graph like this

```
320 a ============================================================
160 b ==============================
 80 c ===============
 40 d =======
 20 e ===
 10 f =
  5 g 
  2 h 
  1 i 
  2 j 
 17 k ===
 41 l =======
 67 m ============
 97 n ==================
127 o ========================
157 p =============================
191 q ====================================
227 r ===========================================
257 s ================================================
283 t =====================================================
331 u ==============================================================
367 v =====================================================================
373 w ======================================================================
379 x ========================================================================
383 y ========================================================================
389 z ==========================================================================
```

Is there something that will work on Windows and Linux? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: [Look here for windows version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812224/getting-terminal-size-in-c-for-windows), for crossplatform you would need a library such as ncurses.

Answer (score 13):

Use GetWindowRect

```
RECT rect;
if(GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect))
{
  int width = rect.right - rect.left;
  int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
}
```

Comment: The pixel dimensions returned by GetWindowRect mean nothing if you don't know the font size...

Comment: This answers the title, but not the question, which clearly is dealing with console mode.

Comment: Does it include the titlebar?

Comment: Yes, this does include the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use **GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo** or one of its siblings.
You are interrested in the dzSize field of the "returned" struct.
Read documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You already have a solution for Linux.

On Windows the API call you need is [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171.aspx).

This returns a [`CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682093.aspx) struct, from which you read out the `dwSize` member:

> A COORD structure that contains the size of the console screen buffer, in character columns and rows.