# What is "lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo" on function GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window

I've just wanted to get the window Width and the window Height using the returned struct of the function `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo();` from header `ConsoleApi2.h`. I referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005992/c-how-to-get-the-window-size-width-and-height). But then I discovered that this function needs a type `_Out_` `PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` parameter called `lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo`. Which values do I need to pass as that parameter?

Here is the function head:

```
WINBASEAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
    _In_ HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
    _Out_ PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo
    );
```

**Or if there is any other way to get the window Width and Height?**

THANKS.

Comment: As [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) says, you need to pass "a pointer to a `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` structure that receives the console screen buffer information"

Comment: Hi jCoder, does the answer's code work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the function a pointer to a `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` variable for it to fill in, eg:

```
HANDLE hConsole = ...;
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info = {};
if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &info)) {
    // use info as needed...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used it for my GDI window but it always returns `0`.

Comment: @jCoder if `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()` returns FALSE, you can call `GetLastError()` to find out why. However, you can't pass a handle to a GDI window to `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()`, you must pass a handle to an active console screen buffer, which you can get from `GetStdHandle()`, `CreateFile()`, or `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()` (See [Console Handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles))