# getenv("LINES") doesnt work on windows

Tags: c++, windows

i tried to use `LINES = atoi(getenv("LINES"))` in windows (visual studio 2012), but it doesn't work. 
Someone told me that I have to add `export LINES` to .bashrc or .profile. 
Will that solve my problem?

If it does, how to add `export LINES` to .bashrc or .profile?

Comment: Please see the example posted in an earlier stack overflow post.
[Getting Terminal Size in C for Windows][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812224/getting-terminal-size-in-c-for-windows

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly want [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the screen buffer info (and [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the console handle).

Answer (score 1):

There's neither .bashrc nor .bash_profile on Windows. In order to get the current console window size, use the `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` API. Look it up. Since the window is resizable, you might want to watch that size. Use `ReadConsoleInput` or `PeekConsoleInput` to check for window resizing.

Why are you trying to get the console window dimensions, and why won't you write a proper GUI application instead?

Comment: <flame>How proper is GUI application?</flame>

Comment: In Windows, that's a technical term. As opposed to console or a driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Visual Studio, and you just set the `LINES` variable, you need to first restart the IDE after setting the environment variable. Otherwise, `getenv()` will not return it in the processes spawned by the IDE.