# PDCurses getmaxxy function always returns the same values

Tags: c++, console, ncurses, pdcurses

## Environment:

- PDCurses latest version
- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

## Problem

PDCurses provides a function `getmaxxy` to get the maximum x and y coordinates of the screen. This returns correct values on startup, but if I resize the window with the mouse and then call `getmaxxy` again, I get back the same values.

Is this a bug/limitation in pdcurses?  Is there a windows specific way to get this information instead?

I have also tried this windows specific solution and it too, always returns the startup values: [Getting terminal size in c for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812224/getting-terminal-size-in-c-for-windows)

Comment: Having never used the library I don't know if this is right or not but to me `getmaxxy` sounds like a function that will give you the maximum window size possible and not the current window size.  Can you check that?

Comment: It correctly returns the size that the console is when the program first starts.  It never changes, whether you make the window larger or smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the source,

- the `_maxx` and `_maxy` members of `WINDOW` are set only when creating a window (including duplicating a window).
- `stdscr` is a window

If you have resized the screen, then you should tell PDCurses about the new size, using `resize_term` (a function adapted from ncurses), e.g.,

```
resize_term(new_lines, new_cols);
```

and *that* recreates the standard windows such as `stdscr`.

For what it's worth, PDCurses provides these functions for compatibility with ncurses:

- [curses_version](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_extend.3x.html#h3-curses_version)
- is_termresized (should have been [is_term_resized](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-is_term_resized))
- [resize_term](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-resize_term)
- [wresize](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/wresize.3x.html)

Comment: I see, so I need to use OS specific code to detect that the window has been resized, and figure out what to tell ncurses/pdcurses, it sounds like.

Comment: ncurses has a `SIGWINCH` handler, and updates the screensize after reading `KEY_RESIZE`, but nothing exists for pcurses - some work needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for a `KEY_RESIZE`, and if it occurs, call `resize_term(0, 0)`. You can see several examples of this in the demos (in testcurs, rain and worm). `is_termresized()` can be used if you're not checking keyboard input.

`resize_term()` is effectively two different functions -- with zeroes as the parameters, it responds to user-initiated resizing; with non-zeroes, it attempts to actually resize the window to the given size. Typically only one or the other capability (or neither) is available on a given platform. SDL allows both.

Comment: I believe that on windows / win32 build KEY_RESIZE does not work, is that correct?