# how to get number of characters in line in console that my process is bind to?

Tags: c++, windows, console, width

Rephrasing my question: width of a console in term of characters.

This in windows is set by default to 80 but user can change it, how to get this value ?

Comment: look at this... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c

Comment: @eharvest: that's for Linux, it doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi))
{
    // an error occourred
    cerr<<"Cannot determine console size."<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"The console is "<<csbi.srWindow.Right-csbi.srWindow.Left<<" wide."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)?