# Get Terminal width Haskell

Tags: haskell, console, functional-programming, terminal, ioctl

How to get the width of the terminal in Haskell?

Things I tried

```
System.Posix.IOCtl (could not figure out how to get it to work)
```

This only has to work unix.

Thanks

Comment: ptyDimensions can do this: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/posix-pty-0.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Pty.html#v:ptyDimensions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't want a dependency on ncurses, here's a wrapper of the appropriate `ioctl()` request using the FFI, based on the accepted answer of [Getting terminal width in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022961/98117)

**TermSize.hsc**

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module TermSize (getTermSize) where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Error
import Foreign.C.Types

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

-- Trick for calculating alignment of a type, taken from
-- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFICookBook#Working_with_structs
#let alignment t = "%lu", (unsigned long)offsetof(struct {char x__; t (y__); }, y__)

-- The ws_xpixel and ws_ypixel fields are unused, so I've omitted them here.
data WinSize = WinSize { wsRow, wsCol :: CUShort }

instance Storable WinSize where
  sizeOf _ = (#size struct winsize)
  alignment _ = (#alignment struct winsize) 
  peek ptr = do
    row <- (#peek struct winsize, ws_row) ptr
    col <- (#peek struct winsize, ws_col) ptr
    return $ WinSize row col
  poke ptr (WinSize row col) = do
    (#poke struct winsize, ws_row) ptr row
    (#poke struct winsize, ws_col) ptr col

foreign import ccall "sys/ioctl.h ioctl"
  ioctl :: CInt -> CInt -> Ptr WinSize -> IO CInt

-- | Return current number of (rows, columns) of the terminal.
getTermSize :: IO (Int, Int)
getTermSize = 
  with (WinSize 0 0) $ \ws -> do
    throwErrnoIfMinus1 "ioctl" $
      ioctl (#const STDOUT_FILENO) (#const TIOCGWINSZ) ws
    WinSize row col <- peek ws
    return (fromIntegral row, fromIntegral col)
```

This uses the [`hsc2hs` preprocessor](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html) to figure out the correct constants and offsets based on the C headers rather than hardcoding them. I think it's packaged with either GHC or the Haskell Platform, so chances are you'll have it already.

If you're using Cabal, you can add `TermSize.hs` to your `.cabal` file and it'll automatically know how to generate it from `TermSize.hsc`. Otherwise, you can run `hsc2hs TermSize.hsc` manually to generate a `.hs` file which you can then compile with GHC.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [hcurses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hscurses).  Once you've initialized the library, you can use `scrSize` to get the number of rows and columns on the screen.

To use `System.Posix.IOCtl`, you have to define a data type to represent the `TIOCGWINSZ` request, which fills in the following structure:

```
struct winsize {
    unsigned short ws_row;
    unsigned short ws_col;
    unsigned short ws_xpixel;   /* unused */
    unsigned short ws_ypixel;   /* unused */
};
```

You'll need to define a Haskell data type to hold this information, and make it an instance of `Storable`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
import Foreign.Storable
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C

data Winsize = Winsize { ws_row    :: CUShort
                       , ws_col    :: CUShort
                       , ws_xpixel :: CUShort
                       , ws_ypixel :: CUShort
                       }

instance Storable Winsize where
  sizeOf _ = 8
  alignment _ = 2
  peek p = do { ws_row    <- peekByteOff p 0
              ; ws_col    <- peekByteOff p 2
              ; ws_xpixel <- peekByteOff p 4
              ; ws_ypixel <- peekByteOff p 6
              ; return $ Winsize {..}
              }
  poke p Winsize {..} = do { pokeByteOff p 0 ws_row
                           ; pokeByteOff p 2 ws_col
                           ; pokeByteOff p 4 ws_xpixel
                           ; pokeByteOff p 6 ws_ypixel
                           }
```

Now, you need to create a dummy data type to represent your request:

```
data TIOCGWINSZ = TIOCGWINSZ
```

Finally, you need to make your request type an instance of `IOControl`, and associate it with the `Winsize` data type.

```
instance IOControl TIOCGWINSZ Winsize where
  ioctlReq _ = ??
```

You will need to replace the `??` with the constant represented by `TIOCGWINSZ` in your header files (`0x5413` on my system).

Now, you are ready to issue the `ioctl`.  This command does not care about the input data, so you want to use the `ioctl'` form:

```
main = do { ws <- ioctl' 1 TIOCGWINSZ
          ; putStrLn $ "My terminal is " ++ show (ws_col ws) ++ " columns wide"
          }
```

Note that the 1 refers to STDOUT.

Phew!

Comment: Isn’t this a bit overkill? Is there nothing simpler?

Comment: Note: The `0` in the `ioctl'` call refers to STDIN, so this fails if STDIN is redirected. Assuming the goal for getting the terminal width is to format output, it may be better to query STDOUT instead.

Comment: Good point.  I've updated my answer, but your answer is far more robust.  I wish I could give you more than 1 up-vote; your answer if chocked full of useful information!

Answer (score 3):

Since you need this only on Unix, I'd recommend:

`resizeOutput <- readProcess "/usr/X11/bin/resize" [] ""`

And then doing a little-bit of parsing of the output. This may not be 100% portable, but I do believe you can provide `resize` with arguments (check out `-u` in particular), so you'll get fairly consistent output.

Comment: the command `/usr/X11/bin/resize` doesn't even exist on arch ^^