# How do I get the terminal size?

Tags: haskell, terminal, environment-variables

In bash there are two environmental variables: `COLUMNS` and `LINES` that store the number of columns and rows for the terminal. I have been trying to obtain that information in Haskell.

Since unlike ruby Haskell's run-time doesn't calculate that by default, I resorted to calling `stty size`. However, calling this command from Haskell with

```
readProcess "stty" ["size"] ""
```

results in the following run-time error:

```
readCreateProcess: stty "size" (exit 1): failed
```

What would be a good way to retrieve such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the [System.Console.Terminal.Size](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/terminal-size-0.3.2.1/docs/System-Console-Terminal-Size.html) package, which in turn is based on [Get Terminal width Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806053/get-terminal-width-haskell/12807521#12807521)