# How can I align text to the center in terminal?

Tags: c

I want to have my text horizontally aligned to the center in the terminal. How can I do this in C?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You'll probably want ncurses or similar.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c

Comment: How about using `printf("%*s\n", strlen(s) + (80 - strlen(s)) / 2, s);` or the ncurses library?

Comment: Check your math, @H2CO3.  I think you want 40 - strlen(s)/2, which would be just (80 - strlen(s))/2.

Comment: @AdamLiss Check your local copy of the documentation of `printf()` :) It takes field width, not initial padding, and anyway **I just tried it...**

Comment: Ah, of course.  Sorry for the silly error!  Why not repeat your comment as an answer (and use COLUMNS as well), so we can upvote it?  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on @eyalm's answer: if you got the `COLUMNS` var, you can center strings like this:

```
int columns = strtol(getenv("COLUMNS"), NULL, 10);
int fwidth = strlen(s) + (columns - strlen(s)) / 2;
printf("%*s\n", fwidth, s);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with bash, use `COLUMNS` environment variable to get the width and calculate the center.

Comment: ... which would be getenv("COLUMNS")/2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but I thought I would add this.

With a bit of maths, you are able to do the following:

```
char *myText = "Hello, world!";
int x, y;
getmaxyx(stdscr, y, x);
mvaddstr(stdscr, y / 2, (x / 2) - (strlen(mytext) / 2)), myText);
```

The way it works:

You get half of the screens width, and subtract it by half of the length of the text. This will center your text to the screen. (It works for any window size!)

Answer (score -5):

If your to lazy like me to write all that code here is a easy solution.

```
 Console.WriteLine("                  Hello World");
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Add more space if needed until its center LOL