# Determine number of lines in terminal

Tags: bash, d

I would like to write a short d program that fills the screen with pound symbols. Here is what I have

```
import std.stdio;
import std.process;
import std.conv;

void main(string[] args){
  auto lines =  environment.get("LINES");
  int line_count = to!int(lines); 
  for(int a = 1; a <= line_count; a++){
    writeln("######################################################################");
  }
}
```

I expected this to work because when I execute "echo $LINES" from the terminal it prints "47". However, LINES appears empty when I run the program via rdmd in the same session. This is on Ubuntu Raring. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you invoke `stty size`?

Comment: Yes. That works. Add it as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can grab the output of the command `stty size`, that's probably more reliable than examining the `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` environment variables.

Or you can invoke the `TIOCGWINSZ` ioctl as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022961/827263).

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a simple fix, you can put `export LINES COLUMNS` in your `~/.bashrc` to make these variables available in your program.

For a proper solution, you could try to invoke the ioctl TIOCGWINSZ, or find a D library that supports querying the terminal (such as ncurses wrappers).

Comment: There are two such libraries, ycurses and dcruses. However, the easiest solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c .