# How to get the terminal dimensions in C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, terminal

I was recently trying to get the size of the terminal in which this program is run.
The problem is that the script + program solution is not handy and it does not support user input or terminal size change.

How can I do that in the C++ code (without messing with the scripts)?
My code:
Bash file (file to be run instead of the C++ program):

```
cols=`tput cols`
lines=`tput lines`
input="${cols}\n${lines}"
echo -ne "${input}" | [C++ program]
```

C++ file (the actual program):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  unsigned lines;
  unsigned cols;
  cin >> cols;
  cin >> lines;
  // some code here
}
```

Comment: Use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Comment: [Getting terminal width in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)

Comment: `system("tput cols")...` could do the trick I think, but I've never tried.

Comment: I installed it but when I compile code with ncurses I get a message that ncurses is not present.

Comment: You have to *link* to ncurses as well.

Comment: I would like to know how

Comment: It's usually `-lncursesw` or `-lncurses` at the end of your compile command

Comment: I added the -lncursesw option but it did not work. Using g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you want to use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

So install the development package (on Debian: `aptitude install libncurses5-dev`), then :

1. add

   ```
   #include  <ncurses.h>
   ```

   to your source code.
2. Link with it, i.e. compile with

   ```
   g++ -Wall yourcode.cc -lncurses -o yourprog
   ```
3. Call the appropriate functions. Read the [ncurses programming HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Comment: why not just ioctl to get winsize?

Comment: Because in general, if you care about the terminal, you want to write in it, and `ncurses` is the right library for that.

Answer (score 8):

As showed in

[Getting terminal width in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1022957/1141471)

you can get terminal size with ioctl call

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);

    printf ("lines %d\n", w.ws_row);
    printf ("columns %d\n", w.ws_col);
    return 0;
}
```