# How to control the terminal ouput format in linux?

Tags: c, format, ls

My task is to write a another small version of LS command. I successful read a directory and stored names of files into an sorted array. My question is how do I print out them in a column format. And how to use system call ioctl() to help me with the format?

```
   $ ls
   file.txt       file2.txt      file5.txt      file8.txt
   file0.txt      file3.txt      file6.txt      file9.txt
   file1.txt      file4.txt      file7.txt
```

Comment: Use tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment. `ioctl` isn't related to formatting as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `filenames` is an array containing C strings with the filenames and `filenames_size` is the amount of C strings in that array.

```
char **filenames;
size_t filenames_size;
size_t filenames_len = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < filenames_size; ++i) {
    size_t len = strlen(filenames[i]);
    if (filenames_len < len) {
        filenames_len = len;
    }
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < filenames_size; ++i) {
    printf("rwxrwxrwx %-*s 10KB\n", filenames_len, filenames[i]);
}
```

`printf` can pad the string, which is what we do here. First get the longest filename, then use that to pad the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your response Benno. But I just need to print out the names of a files in a column format. No other information about the files is required. For example, char *filename[] = {file1.txt, file2.txt..........file10.txt}.

Comment: my professor tells me to use ioctl() as a hint to do the column format.

Comment: I think I got your question wrong. I'll try and edit it as soon as possible. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1022961/2703418

Comment: @stanlopfer Look for the `TIOCGWINSZ` IO-control. It tells you how large the terminal window is.