# How can I get the terminal width in Fortran?

Tags: io, terminal, fortran, fortran90

Is there any possibilty  to get the terminal line width in Fortran (90) beside calling `tput cols`, which, if possible, is cross platform?

I am only using gfortran, so it is sufficient if it works with this compiler.

Comment: Hi, welcome at StackOverflow. You shouldn't put tags into the question if it is not a natural part of it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: You are much better using Fortran 2008 features, because they include interaction with the operating system (like `execute_command_line()`). Fortran 90 is too old.

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you for editing.
Does Fortran 2008 include such a thing as getting terminal width or do I have to call different command depending on the operation system?
Edit: accidently pressed Enter to early

Comment: `call get_environment_variable( "COLUMNS", stmp ); read( stmp, * ) cols` seemed to work, but I experienced it doesn't work sometimes... (so it might be not reliable) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1022984/3501546

Comment: For me the COLUMNS variable is only set in Linux (tested with zsh) but e.g. not in Windows. But this nevertheless seems like a reasonable alternative for calling `tput cols` as it is easier to handle.

Comment: `COLUMNS` does not exist in Fortran code runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal/console functionality is always a system depends feature. It means, that getting a terminal width will be different for Unix and Windows systems. One of the library that can help you is ncurses, writen in C language. There are some Fortran interfaces for this library, like [this](http://www.urbanjost.altervista.org/LIBRARY/libscreen/ncurses/pdsrc/ncurses_from_Fortran.html) uses Fortran 2003.

If this library will fit your requirements, please look at integer variables LINES and COLS defined in , they will be filled with the size of the screen.

In Fortran interface, mentioned before, there are getmaxyx subroutine:

```
subroutine getmaxyx(win,y,x) bind(C, name='macro_getmaxyx')
   use iso_c_binding
   use ncurses_types
   type (C_PTR), value :: win
   integer(C_INT) :: y,x
end subroutine
```

it stores the size of the specified window.

Comment: Thank you, that was the kind of answer I was looking for. The library unfortunatly does not exist for Windows, but this sounds at least on Linux much more reliable than calling `tput cols` or getting environment variables.