# Full width progress bar in console

Tags: c, linux, unix, terminal, console

I'm having trouble adding progress bar for my calculation tool (written in c). Having a simple progress bar code, I can print progress:

```
void print_progress(float progress) 
{
    int barWidth = 70;
    int pos = barWidth * progress;

    printf("%c",'[');

    for (int i = 0; i < barWidth; ++i) 
    {
        if (i < pos) {
            printf("%c",'=');
        }
        else if (i == pos) {
            printf("%c",'>');
        }
        else {
            printf("%c",' ');
        }
    }

    printf("] %f%% \r",(progress * 100.0));
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Though, it prints only a fixed width progress bar. How can I change this to read the screen width and print a full-width progress bar? (Like `wget` or `apt-get` progress bars)

**UPDATE**

What I tried so far is to read terminal width using ioctl :

```
struct winsize max;
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ , &max);
printf ("columns %d\n", max.ws_col); // Always 70
```

And also I don't want to add a dependency like `ncurses`...

**UPDATE 2**

Final (not working) version:

```
void loadbar(unsigned int x, unsigned int n, unsigned int max_width) {
    struct winsize ws;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);
    int barWidth = ws.ws_col;
    if(barWidth > max_width) {
        barWidth = max_width;
    }
    float ratio  =  x/(float)n;
    int   c      =  ratio * barWidth;
    printf("%s","[");
    for (x=0; x<c; x++) {
        printf("%s","=");
    }
    printf("%s",">");
    for (x=c+1; x<barWidth; x++) {
        printf("%s"," ");
    }
    printf("] %03.2f%%\r",100.0*ratio);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: You have a fixed `barWidth`, right? How do you want it to expand-contract _automatically_?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes i have a fixed barWidth, and I want it not to be fixed: Read current terminal width instead.

Comment: So, what is your attempt in that?

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: It's going to be OS dependent, so...are you on Windows, Linux, MacOS,...?

Comment: [Possibly relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Updated my question.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis It should work on Unix-like systems. Basically Linux

Comment: Looks like `ncurses` is really the best way to go here

Comment: why do you believe that the size returned is wrong?

Comment: @F.bernal cause it does not change when I resize the terminal window (as it does for `wget`)

Comment: @sorush-r: Does the `COLUMNS` environment variable (`echo $COLUMNS`) correctly reflect the window width? Does your program catch or ignore the `WINCH` signal? Are you using a local terminal (a terminal window on a Linux machine), or are you connecting remotely via SSH (say, using PuTTY from a Windows machine)?

Comment: Looks like this question really is a duplicate of [the question I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c); voting to close as dupe.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use**:

```
struct winsize w;
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);

printf ("lines %d\n", w.ws_row);
printf ("columns %d\n", w.ws_col);
```

Answer (score 0):

Print progress bar over the full width of the console by first getting console column width:

```
system("clear");

struct winsize w;
ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);

int barWidth = w.ws_col - 10;

float progress = 0.0;

while (progress < 1.0) {
    printf("\r%3d%% ", int(progress * 100.0));
    int pos = barWidth * progress;
    for (int i = 0; i < barWidth; i++) {
        if (i <= pos) printf("\u258A");
        else printf(" ");
    }
    fflush(stdout);

    progress += 0.02; // test

    usleep(100000);
}
printf("\r100%%\n");
```

[column 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KlTr.png)

[column 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH4gb.png)

[column 123](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcRNX.png)

Comment: Can you explain your answer?