# Fill entire Console screen with a particular character using loops

Tags: c, loops, console, screen

I'm programming in C language(Code::Blocks). I don't want infinite loop. Loop should stop when screen is filled once.

**I did it by checking my screen's resolution and adjusting loop conditions according to that.** But now it's limited to that resolution. Even if I maximize my console window,it gets disturbed.

What can be the condition or approach to make it resolution-independent?

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: duplicate [Getting terminal width in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)