# How to communicate with C stdout?

Tags: c, terminal, character, stdout, non-ascii-characters

How can I tell which way my terminal expects to received data? Should I use `fputc`, `fputwc`, or something else?

Here is what I've tried with `fputc`:

```
// characters.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    for ( int c = 0 ; c <= 65535 ; c ++ )
            if ( isgraph ( c ) ) fputc ( c , stdout ) ;
}
```

And with `fputwc`:

```
// wcharacters.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wcahr.h>
int main ( void )
{
    for ( wchar_t c = 0 ; c <= 65535 ; c ++ )
            if ( isgraph ( c ) ) fputwc ( c , stdout ) ;
}
```

With `characters.c`, the output is consistent with the ASCII characters for the first few items printed on the terminal (`!"#`, etc.), then, after `~`, it's garbage.

I get similar results with `wcharacters.c`, except that instead of garbage it's `?`'s or some other ASCII character (but with the great majority being `?`'s).

I know the same terminal supports many character representations in in the Unicode code point range 33 to 65535 (*decimal*), as I can print many of those characters using Python 3.

I am using [Trisquel GNU/Linux](https://trisquel.info/), [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (`-std=c99`), and the "[MATE Terminal](https://mate-desktop.org/)." The font is "Monospace," which sounds generic, but it seems to support many more characters beyond the ASCII range.

I am open to using a more recent C standard. At the same time, one of the points of the project I am working on is simplicity, and the C standard seems to become more and more complicated with each successive standard (would using C17's `uchar.h` be simpler?).

With the function I am working on, the user should be able to write any of the graphic characters (as in `isgraph`) to `stdout` *and have the appearance of those characters be "correct."*

### Addendum

In response to @chux-reinstate-monica:

> `isgraph()` OK with narrow characters, not for wide ones.

A better test than `characters.c` might be:

```
// charactersAll.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    const int cmax = (
        (unsigned) UCHAR_MAX < (unsigned) INT_MAX
            ) ? (int) UCHAR_MAX : INT_MAX ;
    int c = -1 ;
    while ( c < cmax )
    {
        c ++ ;
        if ( isgraph ( c ) ) fputc ( c , stdout ) ;
    }
}
```

vs. characters.c:

- loop through full range of valid `isgraph` arguments.
- avoid overflow: `characters.c` potentially attempts to increment `c` past maximum value (i.e., when `int` is 16-bit; acknowledgement: @chux-reinstate-monica, "aside").

Comment: `The font is "Monospace,"` There are "fallbacks", when the codepoint is lacking from the font you are using as default, another font is checked if it has the character. On my system in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf` and `60-generic.conf` with `<alias< binding="same"><family>emoji</family<prefer>...`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tell which way my terminal expects to received data?

`isgraph()` OK with narrow characters, not for wide ones.

Best to use a restricted range with `is...()` functions, not [0 ... 65535].

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.  C17dr § 7.4 1

`is...()` is not useful for values outside that range.

---

Aside: `for ( wchar_t c = 0 ; c <= 65535 ; c ++ )` risks an infinite loop when `wchar_t` is 16-bit unsigned.

---

GTG.

Answer (score 0):

You could not print the unicode point directly, most terminal only accept UTF8 encoded string by default.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * Encode a code point using UTF-8
 *
 * @author Ondřej Hruška <ondra@ondrovo.com>
 * @license MIT
 *
 * @param out - output buffer (min 5 characters), will be 0-terminated
 * @param utf - code point 0-0x10FFFF
 * @return number of bytes on success, 0 on failure (also produces U+FFFD, which uses 3 bytes)
 */
int utf8_encode(char *out, uint32_t utf)
{
  if (utf <= 0x7F) {
    // Plain ASCII
    out[0] = (char) utf;
    out[1] = 0;
    return 1;
  }
  else if (utf <= 0x07FF) {
    // 2-byte unicode
    out[0] = (char) (((utf >> 6) & 0x1F) | 0xC0);
    out[1] = (char) (((utf >> 0) & 0x3F) | 0x80);
    out[2] = 0;
    return 2;
  }
  else if (utf <= 0xFFFF) {
    // 3-byte unicode
    out[0] = (char) (((utf >> 12) & 0x0F) | 0xE0);
    out[1] = (char) (((utf >>  6) & 0x3F) | 0x80);
    out[2] = (char) (((utf >>  0) & 0x3F) | 0x80);
    out[3] = 0;
    return 3;
  }
  else if (utf <= 0x10FFFF) {
    // 4-byte unicode
    out[0] = (char) (((utf >> 18) & 0x07) | 0xF0);
    out[1] = (char) (((utf >> 12) & 0x3F) | 0x80);
    out[2] = (char) (((utf >>  6) & 0x3F) | 0x80);
    out[3] = (char) (((utf >>  0) & 0x3F) | 0x80);
    out[4] = 0;
    return 4;
  }
  else {
    // error - use replacement character
    out[0] = (char) 0xEF;
    out[1] = (char) 0xBF;
    out[2] = (char) 0xBD;
    out[3] = 0;
    return 0;
  }
}

int main ( void )
{
    char out[6];
    for ( uint32_t c = 0 ; c <= 65535 ; c ++ ) {
        utf8_encode(out, c);
        printf("%s", out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: when `c == 0`, `printf("%s", out);` prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> How to communicate with C stdout?

It is very implementation defined.

> I am using ... GNU/Linux

To communicate with Linux [terminal driver](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html), you use [ioctls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c) or `termios.h` libraries. To communicate with the real terminal, you can set the output to be raw and send a [special escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and then you get answer to stdin. For example `ESC[6n  request cursor position` reports as `ESC[#;#R)`.

> How can I tell which way my terminal expects to received data?

From locale. For example `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` means it wants in `UTF-8`, `LC_ALL=tr_TR.ISO-8859-9` means it wants characters in `ISO-8859-9` encoding.

Note that from [cppreference setlocale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale):

> During program startup, the equivalent of setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); is executed before any user code is run.

It's typical to do `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` right after `main` to use terminal's locale.

> Should I use fputc, fputwc, or something else?

Does not matter, but you should use **one** of them, once the stream is switched it's hard to switch it back. With `fputc` you can output the same [multibyte characters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte) as wide characters with `fputwc`, but surely, there may be a situation where there is no multibyte character for wide character. On Linux with UTF-8 locale, with `fputc` you can output the same UTF-8 code points as with `fputwc` with UTF-32. [GLIBC Extended char intro](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extended-Char-Intro.html) is a good read.

When you use `fputwc`, behind the scenes `glibc` converts UTF-32 to locale specific encoding, somewhere about [behind here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/iofwide.c.html#176) initialized [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/iofwide.c.html#111). It basically calls `iconv` for each character.

> after ~, it's garbage.

`isgraph ( c )` is invalid for `c` greater than `UCHAR_MAX` and `c` different from `EOF`. `#include <wcahr.h>` is invalid.

I have locale `LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8`. The following program:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    for (wchar_t c = 63000; c <= 65535; c++)
        if (iswgraph(c))
            fputwc(c, stdout);
}
```

will output some graphic characters:

```
...
```

As mentioned, you can do the same with `fputc` if you wanna:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    for (wchar_t c = 63000; c <= 65535; c++) {
        if (iswgraph(c)) {
            char s[MB_LEN_MAX];
            wctomb(s, c);
            for (char *p = s; *p; ++p) {
                fputc(*p, stdout);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> except that instead of garbage it's ?'s or som

Your program is using `C` locale. `C` locale can't represent anything other than ASCII.

> would using C17's uchar.h be simpler?

Use `wchar_t`. It depends on your specific application. In the usual cases, let's trust C standard and C implementations and operating systems and use `wchar_t` as the "ultimate" character.